# Replace URL in Angular environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to modify the URL after opening a new window and navigating to a state.

My starting page looks like this:
`localhost:8000/startpage.html`.
When it loads the URL becomes
`localhost:8000/startpage.html#/`.
In the new window I am navigating to a new state:
`localhost:8000/startpage.html#/newstate`.

What I want is to have the URL looking like this:
`localhost:8000/startpage.html?project=1#/newstate`.

I am getting almost correct results except that instead of replacing the URL completely it adds
`?project=1#/newstate` to `localhost:8000/startpage.html#/`.

So the result is something like this:
`localhost:8000/startpage.html#/%3Fproject=903%23/newstate`
while what I need is:
`localhost:8000/startpage.html?project=903#/newstate`

Here is some relevant code:

```
if ($window.history.replaceState) {
    var newUrl = '?project=903' + '#/case';
    $location.path(newUrl);
    $location.replace();
};
```

Seems to me I am having two problems. Extra '#/' after '.html' and the URL is encoded. Because even if I remove extra '#/' it still does not work unless I replace encoded characters with real ones. 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  the `#` denotes the portion which is handled by Angular vs the portion that is being handled by the server.  A URL like `localhost:8000/startpage.html?project=1#/newstate` suggests that you want to send `project=1` to your server and have it send back a new page, which would have a new angular app, which is then directed to the `newstate`.  This seems rather cumbersome......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong method. You want to be using `$location.url` which will allow you to set the `path`, `query`, and `hash` values all at once. But you may be better off setting the `query` and `hash` separately because you don't need to change the entire url.

```
$location.search('project', '903');
$location.hash('case');
```

I removed the `/` from the `hash` because it isn't necessary.

Also, by default angular uses hash mode to navigate its routes. If you want to supply a hash I think you will need to turn that behavior off.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Set that in your application's configuration.

Here is a good article: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: No, then it looks like this:  localhost:8000/startpage.html#/case?project=903#%2Fcase

Comment: Are you accidentally adding the `#` manually when calling `$location.hash`?

Comment: No, I have just these two lines: $location.search('project', '903'); $location.hash('case');

Comment: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); Should I use false as a parameter?

Comment: No you want to use `true`. That will prevent Angular from using hashes and instead uses HTML5 History API. Granted, I don't know the browser support for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129579/discussion-between-mark-and-adam-beck).

Answer (score 1):

With AngularJs 1 the # sign usually follows the page that loads the ngApp Directive... pls correct me if i am wrong.

So i think the only solution to that is to  have ngApp directive on the page link where you want the # tag appear...

It is a very bad practice tho.